# Regex match everything up until specific number + character sequence

Tags: regex

I am trying to match on product titles up until their pack size.

Examples:

- Glen 20 Disinfectant Spray Original Scent 300g
- Devondale 100% Pure Full Cream Long Life Milk 1l
- Maggi 2 Minute Instant Wholegrain Beef Noodles 5 Pack

To return:

- Glen 20 Disinfectant Spray Original Scent
- Devondale 100% Pure Full Cream Long Life Milk
- Maggi 2 Minute Instant Wholegrain Beef Noodles

Matching on numbers using [^0-9]* does not take into account names including numerical values.

Is there a [^0-9]* AND (g|l| Pack) combo i could use?

Comment: Please define "pack size". There are many possible definitions that are consistent with your examples, but not necessarily with other strings you may wish to examine. Neither have you told us if the pack size is always at the end of the string.

Comment: Pack size is always at the end of the string.

Comment: When responding to questions asking for clarification it's best to edit your question rather than elaborating in comments. You still haven't defined "pack size".

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regex pattern:

```regex
^.*(?=\s+\d+\w*(?: \w+)?$)
```

### Demo

This regex pattern says to match:

```regex
^.*                      all content from the start
(?=\s+\d+\w*(?: \w+)?$)  until hitting a number with optional trailing
                         word characters, followed by space and optional unit,
                         at the end of the input
```